# How to delete a collection with a Return and Tab character in its name

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I stumbled on a weird situation where I created by mistake some records that I now can't remove.

Here is how it happened :

```
db.collection(`
   ${
    collectionName
   }/${
    someId
   }/${
    someNestedCollection
}`).add(someObject);
```

When it should have been :

```
db.collection(
   `${
     collectionName
    }/${
     someId
   }/${
    someNestedCollection
   }`)
   .add(someObject);
```

In case you didn't spot the issue at stake, it resides in that fact there is a return character and some tab spaces between the first ` and ${ which introduced some noise in the path name.
Unfortunately Firebase does not trim paths but the console does trim the path when it displays it.
So I don't know how to remove this newly created collection.
When I try to remove it from the console it asks me to type in the collection name.
It is expecting to find that return character and some tabs at the beginning of the path but you can't type those on an input field.

Can anyone help please ?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your database and explain where you wanted to add the data and where it is being added ?

Comment: Data in the screen is confidential. I can't share it here. In the console, display wise, collectionName appears twice exactly the same way. When I go to delete the undesired one, the placeholder that shows the name of the colleciton to remove appears with some spaces in it. I tried many combinations to match the string but it didn't work

Comment: Can you add some sample data and then share it perhaps?

Comment: Maybe firebabse CLI will help to delete wrongly named collection https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#firestore-commands - "firestore:delete"

Comment: the issue is that I don't know how to match the path to the wrongly created collection

Comment: @Dharmaraj it's a production environment. I can't add sample Data

Answer (score 1):

You can find the exact name of the collection (incl. spaces) by clicking in the breadcrumb field at the top of the Firestore console, as shown by the following image:

[image]

By clicking the breadcrumb it will switch to edit mode and you can copy the name.

Comment: Good idea but I could not test it. What I did was to delete all documents within that undesired collection and it disappeared